# Cookies asociadas a notificaciones

Tags: javascript, cookies, notificaciones

Estoy usando el plugin cookies.js para guardar el estado de la notificacion,
si el usuario es nuevo aparecera la notificacion si el usuario cierra la notificacion y recarga la pagina ya no debe volver a aparecer la notificacion, el problema es que sigue apareciendo la notificacion

```js
document.cookie = "close=alert"; 
var lascookies = document.cookie;

$(document).on('click','.notifications-block .bar-wrap .bar .close', function(closeNotifications){
  if($('.close').on('click')){
    $(".bar-wrap").remove();
  }else if (Cookies.get('close')) {
    console.log('Ya existe tu visita');
  }else{
    Cookies.set('close','alert',{expires: 5});
    console.log('Bienvenido');
  
  }
})
```

Comment: por un lado estás usando document.cookies y para leer usas Cookies.get que ese ese objeto Cookies? cómo funciona?

Comment: es del plugin de Cookies.js es para obtener la cookie

Comment: Por cierto. si ya estás usando jquery porque no usar el objeto `$.cookie`?

$.cookie("test", "value")
undefined
$.cookie("test")
"value"

Comment: Tengo la sensación de que tus 2 primeras lineas sobreescriben el resto. Por otro lado el primer if siempre dará true porque devuelve un objeto. Y por lo tanto no entrará en el resto de casos no?

Comment: Soy nuevo en jquery y en esto de las cookies desconozco varias funciones pero lo intentare de esa manera muchas gracias